# Loki Music Application

Tags: release-loki, music

Upon installing Loki today and re-setting up my system I imported my music to the native music app and was toying around with editing meta data for my music.  I soon realized that in Loki I was unable to edit genres for multiple songs by highlighting multiple songs and selecting edit.  Yesterday(Freya) I was able to.  Does anyone know if this is a glitch or a feature removed on purpose??

thanks

Comment: Actually this might be consistent behaviour, at least it is true for all fields in the `Edit Song Info` dialog.